# Set a bean property from a dropdown box

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans, javabeans

Hi there I am trying to set a beans value from a drop down menu and I cant seem to get it working and wondered if any of you guys had some advice on how I could fix this

I have put the useBean tag in my head

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css" type="text/css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/grid.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WOWSlider/engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="WOWSlider/engine1/jquery.js"></script>         
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <jsp:useBean id="mybean3" scope="session" class="org.RDO.login.PeriodHandler" />
```

(There is more to my head but its not relevant to my problem)
Then I call the setProperty tag down in dropdown when it is changed `

```
<select name="date" id="dates" onchange="resetBoxes() <jsp:setProperty name="mybean3" property="date"/>">                                        
</select>
```

(The dates are added to the dropdown when the page loads)

And this is the code from my periodHandler class

```
public void setDate(String date){
    this.date = date;       
}
```

Comment: Not really my area of expertise but don't you need to escape quotes  and angular breackets? Change: onchange="resetBoxes() <jsp:setProperty name="mybean3" property="date"/>">.
 To : onchange="resetBoxes() &lt;jsp:setProperty name=&quot;mybean3&quot; property=&quot;date&quot/&gt;">

Comment: No as the > on the end closes the select tag

Comment: True. But you still need to escape the quotes and the angular brackets. Read my comment once again.

Comment: That hasn't solved my problem man, but thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP works on server-side while the `onchange` event would run at the client side (in the browser). So, the way you're thinking that `onchange` would trigger a `<jsp:setProperty>` is flawed.

You either need to submit the form to the same JSP file where it updates the bean value from the passed `<select>` value (as a GET or POST parameter) or pass the value in an AJAX call in the background.